Parentheses and square brackets in assignments
I'm reading the python (3.12.4) documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-python-grammar-assignment_stmt) on assignment statements. According to it, square and round brackets should be equivalent in the context of target_list. For round brackets the following examples work:
a = 1
(a) = 2
(((((a))))) = 3

Though for square brackets doesn't work next example:
[a] = 4

But the documentation says "Assignment of an object to a target list, optionally enclosed in parentheses or square brackets, is recursively defined as follows ...". That is, if the example with one round brackets works, then it should work exactly the same with one square brackets

Keep reading the “as follows”.

@Ry-
[a] - target list enclosed in parentheses or square brackets.
a - single target with no trailing comma
So,  the object is assigned to that target.
But it doesn't

Apparently, you do not quite understand the assignment syntax of Python. Please do not use ad hoc assignment syntax when writing actual code. It'll be a major headache for both yourself and your coworkers. Just use the simple form a = 1, and if you wish to assign multiple targets at once, then do a, b, c = 1, 2, 3. Don't go any further into the weird multiple target assignment syntax of python.

@LukeL: What qualifies as “ad hoc” assignment syntax? Iterable unpacking is pretty straightforward, and it’s rarely used because it’s rarely useful, not because it’s weird.

@Ry Yeah, tuple unpacking assignments may not be "ad hoc", but list unpacking assignment ([a, b, c] = 1, 2, 3) is ad hoc syntax. I've almost never seen them in use, and even if they are used it still doesn't change the fact that it is a very weird and poorly understood syntax. Actually, I think Python should do away with the list unpacking syntax and just keep the tuple unpacking one.


But the documentation says "Assignment of an object to a target list, optionally enclosed in parentheses or square brackets, is recursively defined as follows ...".

What follows is:


If the target list is a single target with no trailing comma, optionally in parentheses, the object is assigned to that target.


Single targets with no trailing comma in square brackets do not meet this criterion, but single targets with no trailing comma in parentheses do.


Else:

…
Else: The object must be an iterable with the same number of items as there are targets in the target list, and the items are assigned, from left to right, to the corresponding targets.




Single targets with no comma in square brackets are handled by this case.

But [a] may be target list of one target, enclosed in square brackets. So the object must be assigned to that target.

@otstalyi: No, that is not what the documentation says.

@otstalyi: I don’t know what you mean by that. “The object must be an iterable with the same number of items as there are targets in the target list”, i.e. an iterable with one item for a list of one target.

@user2357112
Documentation says "Assignment of an object to a target list, optionally enclosed in parentheses or square brackets, is recursively defined as follows." In my case a - target list enclosed in square brackets. Then a - target list of target. Then a - identifier, so " the object is assigned to that target."

@otstalyi: You've quoted documentation saying that assignment is defined, but you're ignoring the part about how it's defined. It is defined to do something entirely different from what you insist it's supposed to do.

Apparently "Assignment of an object to a target list, optionally enclosed in parentheses or square brackets, is recursively defined as follows." Is not part of the expression parsing, as I thought. Thanks.

Still, in my opinion, the documentation in this part is written a little unclearly, because "Assignment of an object to a target list, optionally enclosed in parentheses or square brackets, is recursively defined as follows." means that in the expression "[a]", "a" is a target list enclosed in square brackets. And the assignment is defined for it. But as it was explained now, it is implied that all "[a]" is target list
